# Настройка crossdomain.xml

Tags: ajax, flash, javascript, сервер

Столкнулся с проблемой по настройки crossdomain.xml. Для ие9 хотели использовать флешевый загрузчик файлов (plupload),но его не получается настроить для кроссдоменного запроса.

Есть домен api.dev.domain.com файл находится там же api.dev.domain.com/crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd"> 
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.domain.com" headers="*" secure="true"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="panel.dev.domain.com" headers="*" secure="true" /> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*.domain.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="panel.dev.domain.com" /> 
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />  
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Протокол https, флеш загружает сам файл, но дальше не идет - security error. может кто сталкивался? Решения из нета не помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Советую проверить на других компьютерах, данная проблема сильно "плавает", всё зависит от сочетания: "Браузер" + "Flash player version" + "Сервер".

Обязательно проверьте сертификаты, проблемы может наблюдаться если у вас:

1. self-signed сертификат
2. нормальный сертификат, но не содержит в себе информацию от подписавшего его источника

P.S. У себя использую такой [crossdomain.xml](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/blob/gh-pages/crossdomain.xml). В реальности такая проблема у 5% пользователей, поэтому наша библиотека её детектит и загружает файлы через iframe.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге использую такой, все работает

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.domain.com" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```